# Displaying shapes through user input in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that displays shapes through user input and ouputs them to a window. I have a seperate class which defines the shapes and the graphics window however I can't work out how to get the user input for the shapes. I am new to Java and OOP in general. Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        GraphicsScreen g = new GraphicsScreen();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int val1 = 0;
        int val2 = 0;
        String line; 
        String [] sut;
        System.out.println("Please enter your commands here. Type 'end' to quit.");
        line = s.nextLine();

        while ( line.equalsIgnoreCase("end"));

        sut = line.split(", ");
        line = sut [0];
        if (sut.length > 1) {
            val1 = Integer.parseInt(sut[1]);
            if (sut.length > 2) {
                val2 = Integer.parseInt(sut[2]);
            }
        }
        if (line.equals("moveTo" + val1 + val2)) {
            g.moveTo(val1, val2);
        }
        else if (line.equals("lineTo" + val1 + val2)) {
            g.lineTo(val1, val2);
        }
        else if (line.equals("circle" + val1)) {
            g.circle(val1);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The commands you have entered are invalid. Please try again.");
        }   
    }
}
```

Basically the int's defined at the top have to be set to a value else Eclipse returns an compliler error, so I set them to zero. In the last IF statement I have tried concatenating the values on the end but this would obviously result in shapes with zero value.

How would I go about changing this so the user defines `val1` and `val2` and it outputs that result to the window?

Comment: What are you expecting this line to do? while ( line.equalsIgnoreCase("end"));

Comment: @John3136 I'm guessing while(!line.equalsIgnoreCase("end"))

Comment: Yep, but we have a semicolon at the end of the statement, and no {} to wrap the block we're trying to repeat.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (line.equals("moveTo" + val1 + val2)) {
    g.moveTo(val1, val2);
}
```

Shouldn't this just be

```
if (line.equals("moveTo")) {
    g.moveTo(val1, val2);
}
```

You've already broken the line up at commas.

Comment: Yes, if val1 and val2 were to be fixed values. However they need to be user defined. I was just demonstrating something that I had tried (bit failed to work).

Comment: They are user defined (by the input): right where you say `val1 = Integer.parseInt(sut[1]);` etc.  Have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: That's just changing it to a numerical value, not defining a user input. I need val1 and val2 to be typed in at run time by the user in the following expression : command val1, val2. For example lineTo 100, 100 and the program draws a line at those coords. Hope this helps.

Comment: Really? The program doesn't return the values input at run time. To elaborate, if I type in 'circle, 100' the window doesn't draw anything. However if I change the val1 value to 100 and type 'circle', it does. This tells me there is something wrong with the way the user input is defined in the code.

Comment: Assuming you have fixed your while loop, then you need to use a debugger or just some prints to find out where you are going wrong.